# Can't resolve all parameters for ToastrService: (?, [object Object], [object Object], [object Object], [object Object])

Tags: angular, toastr, angular-toastr

I am applying toasterjs in my angular component. Here is my code.
i have imported the `ToastrService` using the code:

```js
import { ToastrService } from 'ngx-toastr';
```

and inject that service in the constructor

```js
constructor(private toastrService: ToastrService) {    
}

this.toastrService.success('You are awesome!', 'Success!',)
```

But it is giving the following error:

> Can't resolve all parameters for ToastrService: (?, [object Object], [object Object], [object Object], [object Object])

When I go to its definition, then it is taking 4 parameters. Here are the parameters:

```js
success(message?: string, title?: string, override?: Partial<IndividualConfig>): ActiveToast;
```

I have added the module also:

```js
imports: [
    ToastrModule.forRoot(),
    CommonModule,
    HttpModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    TextboxModuleShared,
    DateTimeModuleShared,
    DropdownModuleShared
],
```

So how can I use the parameters because I want to only show success message?

Comment: this.toastrService.success('You are awesome!', 'Success!') not this.toastrService.success('You are awesome!', 'Success!',)

Answer (score 1):

You have imported the `ToastrModule` in your app's NgModule in the incorrect order. It should be imported in the order as indicated by the [documentation](https://github.com/scttcper/ngx-toastr):

```js
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule, // required animations module
    ToastrModule.forRoot(), // ToastrModule added
  ],
  bootstrap: [App],
  declarations: [App],
})
class MainModule {}
```

You should also replace `CommonModule` with `BrowserModule` if this app is running in the browser as indicated [here](https://angular.io/guide/ngmodule-faq#should-i-import-browsermodule-or-commonmodule).

Note that the error doesn't occur while calling the `success` function, but while invoking the constructor of the `ToastrService`. Your error message clearly states that not all parameters for the ToastrService constructor can be resolved. Some of these parameters cannot be resolved, because no instances for those parameters have been created yet. To understand how this works, you should read the [documentation](https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection) on dependency injection within the Angular framework.

Comment: i have added module also but still same error happens

Comment: @Gaurav_0093 could you provide the code of adding the module?

Comment: yes sure NgModule({
    bootstrap: [ AppComponent ],
    imports: [
        ServerModule,
        AppModuleShared,
        ToastrModule.forRoot()
    ]
})

Comment: @Gaurav_0093 that's the module for the server, not for the client. Could you provide the client one?

Comment: please have a look on question here is the module i have edited

Comment: @Gaurav_0093 I have updated my answer based on your changes.

Answer (score 0):

**Point to Consider :**
 I was facing same issue. So here how I get solution

- After installing 'ngx-toastr' Package and updating angular.json file with 'toastr.css
- angular should be  re-run by using ng-serve command, because app is not rendered by changing angular.json file

Answer (score 0):

Try to import 'Inject' decorator and then decorate parameter in constructor and as an argument you should add ToastrService like this:

`constructor(@Inject(ToastrService) private toastyService: ToastrService ) {   }`